# OWIN stop functionning in Azure

Tags: azure-active-directory, owin, azure-ad-msal

I got an old application that run for 2 years now without problems. Recently the login part starts to fail with a 404 Not found.
Here part of the error:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() +94579
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.<GetDocumentAsync>d__8.MoveNext() +375

[IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden]'.]
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.<GetDocumentAsync>d__8.MoveNext() +663
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.<GetAsync>d__3.MoveNext() +291
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) +26
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.<GetConfigurationAsync>d__24.MoveNext() +1129
```

The line that create this 404 error not found is:
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(authenticationProperties);

So something changes in Azure Authentication with old MSAL and OWIN authentication (for B2C Azure)
In the B2C Azur portal, I can see my apps in Applications (Legacy) with this note: The new App registrations experience is now generally available and is the recommended way of registering applications. Click the App registrations blade to access the new experience. The Applications (Legacy) blade has been deprecated and will no longer be available going forward.

Quite annoying because I do not want to make too much time in development for this old app. I try to found some info for migrating this kind of app. Do I have to only create a new App in AD B2C do I have to change my code?
Thanks

EDIT1:
That the code called by the login button. All was working couple month ago. I do not change anything or push anything on Azure on this projet for about 2 years!

```
    public void SignUpSignIn()
    {
        // Use the default policy to process the sign up / sign in flow
        if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            string returnUrl = "/";
            if (Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath != null && Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath != "")
                returnUrl = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath;

            var authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = returnUrl };
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(authenticationProperties);
            return;
        }
```

EDIT 2:
After adding some PII diagnostique I got this detail:
Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/hidenb2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SignInOut/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'

Comment: The deprecation of Legacy blade wont affect the apps which are already registered. You do not need to register the applications again and users of your applications. Please refer the [documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/app-registrations-training-guide#whats-not-changing) for more information. Can you please check wether the redirectURL is `login.microsoftonline.com` or `b2clogin.com`.

Comment: It's an old app, I try to understand what the previous dev do. I think it uses 2 methods. One for login and to get the tocken then use the graphApi to get users groups. In the web.config I got this url for login.microsoft:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/{0}/{1}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
and the tenant is:
myclienttenantb2c.onmicrosoft.com

Comment: I add the function called by the login button

Comment: When I try to see the "real" URL used, I can see in chrome that no URL to microsoft is use. The function just return nothing like of the HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge just do nothing...

Comment: Once the user is logged-in with the received access token you are connecting to Graph API and getting the user,groups. The  redirectURL `login.microsoftonline.com` is depricated you need to be using `b2clogin.com`. Please go this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin) on how to change the redirectUrl

Comment: Yes, but for now my login part to not work. Look at my edit 2. The SignInOut return 404 not found. I think I will recode the login and graph part.

Comment: Let us help you in minimalize the changes. For some troubleshooting if there are no code changes happend in the recent times, have you testing the `B2C_1_SignInOut` UserFlow/Custom policy in the Azure AD B2C tenant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after many tries, I found that I just need to change the URL from

https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/hidenb2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SignInOut/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

to

https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/tfp/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SignInOut/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

now all is working. Thanks for your help.